# Alert auto close con direccionamiento a página

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap-3

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Bootstrap 3.1 y PHP, les pido de su apoyo para integrar un direccionamiento con un `alert auto close` al momento que se desvanece se direccione a otra página.

```
echo '
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in col-sm-3 animated bounceInDown" role="alert" style="position:fixed;  top: 50%; right:40%; z-index:10;">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
  <h4 class="text-center">Actualización de Actividad</h4>
  <p class="text-center">
    El Comentario fue actualizado con exito
  </p>
</div>

';
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    window.setTimeout(function() {

      $(".alert").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }, 2250);

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias Silvestre Silva por la correccion del post se te agardece soy Nuevo colaborador.

Comment: Puedes hacer window.location y hacer el redirect luego del setTimeout.

Comment: Gracias, tu ayuda fue muy util.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver la etiqueta MySQL en la pregunta?

Comment: Disculpa amigo jheyman mejia lo puse de mas la etiqueta  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quedó de la siguiente manera. Gracias a todos por tomarse un tiempo para apoyarme,se los agradesco.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(800, 0).slideUp(800, function() {
      {
        window.top.location = "index.php"
      }
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }, 2000);

});
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in col-sm-3 animated bounceInDown" role="alert" style="position:fixed;  top: 50%; right:40%; z-index:10;">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
  <h4 class="text-center">Actualización de Registro</h4>
  <p class="text-center">
    La Actualizacion fue con exito
  </p>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in col-sm-3 animated bounceInDown" role="alert" style="position:fixed; top:70px; right:10px; z-index:10;">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
  <h4 class="text-center">OCURRIÓ UN ERROR</h4>
  <p class="text-center">
    No hemos podido Actualizar
  </p>
</div>
```